# Magnetic fluxdensity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose a magnetic field with field lines pointing downwards and a conductor shaped as a loop that conducts a current. The conductor is static, and is placed half in the magnetic field. Is there a magnetic flux through the magnetic field or only when it moves?

Because the professor only explained a conductor in moving direction which has a flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first clear some concepts:

A magnetic flux is the integral of the magnetic field over an area. If the magnetic field is constants, you can simply say that the flux is the magnetic field times an area. When studying the current induced due to Faraday's law for example, you must consider the magnetic flux going through a circuit.

In your example, if the magnetic field is only applied in half the area of the loop, the magnetic flux will be equal to the magnetic field times half the area of the loop.

Faraday's law of induction tells us that a **varying magneic flux** will interact with the electric circuit to produce an electromotive force which will produce an electric current. If the loop in your example isn't moving, there won't be  flux change, so no current will be induced.

Comment: Could maybe explain it with concepts that related to the same subject? Faraday's law is in chapter 20 and we're still at chapter 18.

Comment: What is your question? If the question is whether the loop has a magnetic flux, yes it does: the magnetic flux is the magnetic field times the area by definition. If you are asking whether there will be an induced current, the answer is no because there is no flux change.

Comment: It was the magnetic flux part. Ok, so it's just following the definition flux= magnetic field $\times$ the surface vector  $\times$ cos $\theta$. \theta is then the angle between the magnetic field lines and the surface vector, right?

Comment: Yes, but it is a scalar product: $\Phi=\vec{B}\cdot\vec{S}=BS\cos{\theta}$

Comment: Oké. Yeah, you're right. Thank you for clarifying this.